# sqlite3_prepare_v2 failure: no such table Ionic and cordova pluging sqlite

Tags: sqlite, ionic3

I need disable WAL because my app not work in Android Pie for the fallowing error (message: "sqlite3_prepare_v2 failure: no such table: productos"). I read that in Android Pie the WAL option is enabled by default and it is likely that for that reason my app does not work, I'm using ionic 3 and cordova sqlite plugin, someone tell me how i can disable that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39872960/where-to-place-pre-loaded-db-file-in-ionic-2-rc0

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic2-prepopulated-sqlite-db/110423/6

Comment: From what I find of the same error, you likely are not opening the database that you think is opening.  It is probably not a problem with WAL.  Why would you think it is a problem with WAL?

Comment: @CPerkins I think it's a problem with WAL because I read that in Android Pie this option is enabled by default and not in previous versions. The problem gives me versions of androi Pie and higher

Comment: If that is the case, then the question title should make clear that you want to disable WAL journaling mode.  Instead the question appears to be about the error details in the title.   Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to disable WAL on Android SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901460/is-it-possible-to-disable-wal-on-android-sqlite-database)

Comment: Also a possible duplicate of [Disabling sqlite Write-Ahead logging in Android Pie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53659206/disabling-sqlite-write-ahead-logging-in-android-pie/53689702)

Answer (score 0):

I studied the links that suggest me but I don't see those cases being based on ionic projects. How could I implement the disableWriteAheadLogging () that is used in Android, but in ionic.